# Curl does not fall back to ipv4

Tags: linux, linux-networking, docker, ipv6, gentoo

I have gentoo build with ipv6 and ipv4 configured for localhost

/etc/hosts

```
# IPv4 and IPv6 localhost aliases
127.0.0.1   sunils-pc.homenetwork sunils-pc localhost
::1     sunils-pc.homenetwork sunils-pc localhost
```

I have enabled the ipv6 forward as below

```
sunils@sunils-pc ~ $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
1

sunils@sunils-pc ~ $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
1
```

I have ran the docker swarm with docker container exposing web server at 8080. I can access the website using below command

```
curl -4 http://localhost:8080/
```

But when I try to access it using `curl http://localhost:8080/` it hangs for infinite time. From the verbose output it shows its trying to reach the service at ipv4 address and hangs indefinitely without falling back to ipv4.

```
sunils@sunils-pc ~ $ curl -v http://localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

I am not sure where should I investigate further. I am running gentoo linux with ipv6 enabled kernel.

==Update

When I use ipv4 I get the proper HTTP response on terminal, but in case of ipv6 it hangs indefinitely.

```
sunils@sunils-pc ~ $ curl -4 -v http://localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=e20b76f1-78c3-473c-a518-da2519983985; Path=/
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2018 17:13:11 GMT
< 
<!doctype html>
...
```

Comment: It successfully connected to the IPv6 address, so I don't know why you would expect it to fall back to IPv4. Did you try to find out what the server does when receiving the request?

Comment: It hangs indefinitely when I use I do not get any response when it connects it using ipv6,

Comment: There is no reason to believe `curl` is at fault. Either your network configuration is severely messed up, or the server is doing something wrong when requests are received over IPv6.

Comment: Looks like a Docker problem, not a curl problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are successfully connecting to the port via ipv6, per the following message:

```
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
```

Since the connection has entered the ESTABLISHED state, curl deems this as a successful connection to the IPv6 host, and it is correct.

The next thing that happens is that the curl client sends the HTTP request to the localhost(::1) on port 8080. However, the server never responds back with the document that you expect.

There's no reason at this point why curl would re-try with IPv4 as the connection was established with IPv6, however, the server did not send the HTTP payload.

It appears that the issue may be with the server not being properly bound to the IPv6 port, there are two instances of the server running both trying to bind to the IPv6 port 8080, or another problem with the server being bound to the IPv6 port that does not replicate when you use IPv4.

Comment: Thanks, I will now add new question for docker specific details